# force bash completion to use choices supplied by script

Tags: bash, autocomplete

[EDIT: looks like this might be a bug just in my OS X 10.9.5 implementation which uses bash 3.2.51.  Confirmed that it works fine in Linux with bash 4.2.25]

I wondered if anyone knows a work-around to this bash completion behavior.  To illustrate:

1. create a file dummycompleter.sh containing this code:

> ```
> echo "aaa"
> echo "aab"
> ```

2. run this to link your dummy completion script to the "mycomp" command

> complete -C "./dummycompleter.sh" mycomp

3. test it by typing `mycomp c` and press `TAB`

> mycomp aa

works as expected.  Now try typing `mycomp ccc`

> mycomp cc

This is unexpected!  "cc" is not a subset of any of the completion choices!

How can I work around this behavior to be able to use my completion choices, which may have nothing to do with the entered text (much like bash's native ls completion doesn't show the full path to its file suggestions)?

Comment: works for me: I am getting "mycomp aa" as result of the last test with bash version 4.3.11(1) (Ubuntu 14.10).

Comment: Could this be a problem with terminal update? Suppose you actually define mycomp: `mycomp() { echo "$@"; }` and then do the `mycomp ccc` test and hit return. Does it echo `cc`?